# Replace number into line which contains this number

Tags: java

I am trying to use the function `replaceAll()` in order to convert all numbers in a given string to the format `_ARG_#num`.

Example:

I have the sentence: `1And5`.

I would get: `_ARG_1_And_ARG_5_`.

I try to use a regular expression, but it doesn't save me the specific number which I should know when creating `ARG_#num`

Comment: Would you share your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
s.replaceAll("\\d+", "_ARG_$0_");
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it does. They are called "backreferences" and are prefixed with a dollar sign.

`"1And5".replaceAll("\\d+", "_ARG_$0_")`

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html

$0 refers to the whole match. For $1 upward you have to use capturing groups.

Comment: Note that it doesn't work well with multi-digit numbers. See my response.

Comment: That is true. I'll modify the example.